# When using data validation for a field in Access how can I make the expression conditional?

Tags: validation, ms-access

For example, I want the data validation constraints on the field [Level] to be between 0 and 10 if [Upgrade] < 5 and between 0 and 20 if [Upgrade] >= 5 and between 0 and 30 if [Upgrade] >= 10

I'm new to Access and I'm not sure on what to do.

Tried: IIf([Upgrade]>=5, between 0 and 20, between 0 and 10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your validation rule involves more than 1 table column, you have to use a Table Validation Rule rather than a Field Validation Rule.
Put the table in design mode, don't select any fields and on the right you should see the table properties including a validation rule property.  If not hit f4 (or the equivalent) to bring up the properties menu.
Then enter a validation rule like:

```
IIf([Upgrade]>=10,[Level] Between 0 And 30,IIf([Upgrade]>=5,[Level] Between 0 And 20,[Level] Between 0 And 10))
```

note the second iif.  My validation rule does assume upgrade doesn't go below 0 so you might want to include a field validation rule on upgrade like [Upgrade]>0

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
>0 And <=IIf([Upgrade]>=5,20,10)
```